# Predicted values in negative binomial model with 0-inflation

Tags: prediction, model, negative-binomial-distribution, zero-inflation

My count data are zero-inflated, for which I utilized `glmmADMB`.

```
Call:
glmmadmb(formula = NP~ I + D + I*D + (1 | loc), data = dat), family = "nbinom", 
           zeroInflation = T)
```

And here is what I get:

```
Coefficients:
                     Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)             1.369      0.188    7.29  3.1e-13 ***
I1                      0.370      0.263    1.41   0.1593    
Dlo                     0.858      0.285    3.01   0.0026 ** 
I1:Dlo                 -2.007      0.644   -3.11   0.0018 **
```

It is a simple model with simple results. However when trying to check the prediction of this model I get

[image]

The same thing happens when I run a regular negative binomial model without 0-inflation (`glmer.nb`).

Why are there only four distinct predicted values for these models?

My own edit: My model being significantly explained by the 2*2 interaction it makes sense that it predicts only 4 values which are the 4 levels of the interaction...

Comment: Whether or not it's 0-inflated won't change the number of combinations of levels that are in the predictors

Comment: Yes sure- I just wonder why the predicted values consist of only 4 possiblities whereas there are a lot more possibilities in the observed values.

Comment: How many levels do I and D have?

Comment: Both have 2 levels.